# Read a table from Azure SQL database to Azure Databricks

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, jdbc, azure-databricks

I need to read a table hosted in the Azure SQL database service, but I can't find the documentation that solves this problem for me. Your help please.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to read Azure SQL database table into Databricks Notebooks is:

```
df = (spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<server-name>.database.windows.net:<port>;database=<sqldb-name>")
.option("dbtable", "<table-name>")
.option("user", "<userID>")
.option("password", "<password>")
.load()
 )
```

Here the URL should be taken from SQL database connection strings section as shown below till database name:
[image]

Next you can create temporary view and could read the contents of the table:

[image]

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/jdbc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-connect-to-sql-database

Further we can parametrize values and could access the contents of the tables as required.